# Pex: Overflow Exception when int.MinValue % -1 and Strange Path Condition

Tags: pex

I have some questions about the path condition for an input that causes overflow exception in a method. The input is for the PUT for that method and the input is generated by pex. Here is the code of the method:

```
public static int GreatestCommonDenominator(int first, int second)
{
      return second == 0 ? first : GreatestCommonDenominator(second, first % second);   //Exception
}
```

Here is the PUT

```
[PexMethod]
public int GreatestCommonDenominatorTest(int first, int second)
{
      int result = GreatestCommonDenominator(first, second);
      return result;
}
```

The input to the PUT is **(first: -1, second: intMin)**. The exception is triggered in the recursive call. The value of the parameters for that recursive call is **(first: intMin  second:-1)** and the exception is triggered when computing **first % second**. However, I wrote and executed a method in a separate c# project to print out **int.MinValue % -1** and it didn't throw any exception and returned **0**. Then in the that method, I created an int variable **int b = int.MinValue** and computed **b % -1**. After this modification, the overflow exception is thrown on **b % -1**. I'm confused about why this happens?

I obtained the patch condition by using **PexSymbolicValue.GetPathConditionString();** and the path condition for the input  **(first: -1, second: intMin)** is **return first % int.MinValue == -1 && second == int.MinValue && first % second == -1;** I have trouble understanding this path condition. Does the **first** and **second** in the path condition corresponds to the input to the PUT/first invocation of **GreatestCommonDenominator**? Also, it seems like some predicates in the path condition is redundant since **first % int.MinValue == -1 && second == int.MinValue** implies **first % second == -1**.

Comment: I believe int.MinValue % -1 is one of the few things that the C# spec and the CLR leaves implementation defined. A different runtime, bitness or optimization level might change the outcome. Check that.

Comment: Yes, it's in 7.8.2 of the C# spec.